# Beautifulsoup .text function returns no text

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I attempted to extract the text within the h1 tag returned from running the code and received no output. However, the code was able to find the specified tag as follows:

```
<h1 class="product-name main-heading">Mixed Brown Rice 2.5kg</h1>
```

The link to the web page:

```
https://giantonline.com.sg/product/mixed-brown-rice-5142760
```

This is the code I used:

```
driver.get("https://giantonline.com.sg/product/mixed-brown-rice-5142760")
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
time.sleep(4)
bs2=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
for z in bs2.find_all('div',class_="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-12"):
    try:
        name = z.find('h1',class_='product-name')
        print(type(name))
        print(name)
        name = name.get_text(seperator=' ')
        print(name)
        size = z.find('h1',class_='product-size main-heading')
        size = size.text
        oldprice = z.find('div',class_='old-price')
        oldprice = oldprice.text
        price = z.find('div',class_='content_price')
        price = price.text
    except:
        continue
```

Why was I unable to get the text out of the `h1` tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, check this code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """<h1 class="product-name main-heading">Mixed Brown Rice 2.5kg</h1>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
Title = soup.find('h1', attrs={'class':'product-name'}).text
print(Title)
```

Output:

```
Mixed Brown Rice 2.5kg
```

Comment: just did. do you happen to know why the price isn't extracted as well?

Comment: Ok, i'm checking.

Comment: managed to get it to work now. Whats the difference between using `class_=` and `attrs`?

Comment: Check this documentation
https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-keyword-arguments

Comment: You're Welcome :)